# How to get ubuntu server raw image

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization

I want ubuntu as VM in KVM with qcow2 format.

currently I can get the `.iso` format want can convert to the `qcow2` format but this doesn't work.

so for this there cloud image with `.img` format and can be converted to the `qcow2` format with `qemu-img` command and it works but the problem is that it has `cloud-init` which gives errors with the on-prem deployment in KVM

so, conclusion: `qcow2` from `.iso` not working with KVM and `qcow2` with `.img` is working but it has cloud `init`.

I want server ubuntu image with `.img` format with cloud-init.

Comment: create the VM from the .iso the normal way and with what you want, resulting in a.img. Then convert that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying for the whole day, I found out there is no way to provision the Ubuntu VM in KVM with CLI `virsh` command even if you have perfect `qcow2` image.

because the ubuntu wants GUI input to otherwise it will be blocked

and you cannot access the `root` ssh and `virsh console` without explicitly configuring for this

the only solution is to take ubuntu server iso and use `GUI` to install 
and configure the Ubuntu with the above capability and copy the generated `.qcow2` and form the basic `virsh` XML template and then use the copied `.qcow2` image to provision the VM with the `virsh` command and get the console access.